# Problem in shifting range please help me out

Tags: c#

I have small concept problem. I am working on graph.

Consider I have a point 32 between range 28 and 35, and I have to bring all the points between the range 28 and 35 within range 1 and 2.

How to calculate it?

I'll have the point 32, and I have to shift it between 1 and 2.

In other words, if 32 is between 28 and 35, what is 32 in range 1 and 2?

Comment: Consider re-wording this and adding example input and output.

Comment: Can you phrase the question better? Are you just looking for `1 + ( x - 28) / 7)`? You may need clamping, e.g. `Math.Max(1, Math.Min(2, calculatedValue))`

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: if i have a point between a range 28 and 35 say 32... and i want to shift 28 between range 1 and 2.... ie what is the value of 28 between 1 and 2

Comment: This question has nothing to do with silverlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is: 1 + [(number - 28) / (35 - 28)], for example for 32 is (1 + 4/7) = 1.57...

and in general if you want move it within [a,b]:

```
a + (b-a) * [(number - 28) / (35 - 28)]
```